# How to properly install TensorFlow in Mac?

Tags: python

I am trying to install TensorFlow on my MacPro 2.7 GHz Intel Core i5  8 GB 1867 MHz DDR3 | El Capitan.

I used: $ pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.5.0-py2-none-any.whl

This is what I got:
Collecting tensorflow==0.5.0 from [website from above]
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 9.8MB 65kB/s 
Installing collected packages: tensorflow
Successfully installed tensorflow-0.5.0

However, when I open a Python shell and use: 
MacPro:TesnsorFlow myName $ python

> > > import TensorFlow

I get the following messages:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: No module named TensorFlow

I am not sure why it shows like if I am inside of a TensorFlow folder. For example:

MacPro:TesnsorFlow myName $

When I Type MacPro:TesnsorFlow myName $ python I get the error

If you have clear instructions on how to install tensorflow, please share it with me. I tried the instructions from www.tensorflow.org and I got more lost. I even installed Anaconda-Navigator because someone told me it had tensorflow and it did not. Guys/girls, I am trying without any success.

Note: I am having issue with Stackoverflow

Comment: You already have your answer, but for future reference I'd recommend you to use [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads). Also tensorflow is now 1.1.0 version, and there are some dramatic changes between your version. Download the latest. And one last thing, tensorflow has been on [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tensorflow) for a while, you can just use `pip install tensorflow`

Answer (score 1):

Try to install in  virtual-env:

```
pip install TensorFlow
```

Then:

```
import tensorflow
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact, there was nothing wrong with your installation of TensorFlow, it was just an import error.

You should use `import tensorflow` instead of `import Tensorflow` because Python is case sensitive!

Comment: Also , I suggest you using `Pyenv` or `Docker` or `Vitualenv` to play with Tensorflow instead of installing Tensorflow globally!

Answer (score 0):

For me, this worked: `python3 -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0-py3-none-any.whl`

Comment: I'm using macOS Mojave. I tried 'pip install tensorflow' and many other ways, but nothing worked. More info can be found here: https://openagi.github.io/tefla/installation/